# Is echoing a $_GET parameter a website security vulnerability?

Tags: php, get, echo

As the question says, I have found this on my website without escaping it and want to know what can someone do in the worst case? The parameter itself is a search value $_GET["q"].

Comment: When i use ?q=text'">DROP%2520TABLE%2520users--

It gives an error:

Not Acceptable!

An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.

But i escape the text before the query with mysqli_real_escape_string, why is that error even happening?

Answer (score 2):

You're leaving your site open to reflected XSS attacks. So JavaScript could be passed into the parameter and used in the site.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Reflected_Cross_site_scripting_%28OTG-INPVAL-001%29

From the example above such an attack would be along the lines of:

```
http://example.com/index.php?q=<script>alert(123)</script>
```

Comment: And what are the risks of that? I mean, that only changes the client-side page for the attacker only, not for all the people. You can even modify a website client-side with many extensions out there.

Comment: @Agusfn There are numerous ways this could cause problems. The page can be manipulated to show incorrect information. Login forms could be altered for phishing attacks. Session cookies could be stolen for session hijacking.

Comment: @Agusfn They’re called cross-site scripting _attacks_ for a reason: they’re bad.

Comment: The manipulation to show incorrect information or phishing links is only possible if a third party gives their own URL for my website, and not if they enter directly into it, right? Fortunately my website currently doesn't have an user system and does not handle sensible/valuable information.

Could you give me an example on how session cookies can be stolen?

Comment: @Agusfn It'd be worth reading the OWASP page for the details of how it works.

Comment: Thing is, i got an email telling me i had this XSS vulnerability, i don't know how vulnerable is this. The guy pretends a donation he even left his paypal e-mail, i don't even know him, he just appeared out of nowhere.

Comment: Can this vulnerability delete a table or fetch info from the DB?

Comment: He says that even though i have Mod_security, i can be exposed to an attack of type **object**

Comment: @Agusfn without access to your website it's difficult to say what the possible attack vectors are. I'd just fix this and move on.

Comment: I fixed it. Anyway, my main question was if this was a vulnerability with high risk. They can't change anything server-side with this, right? Please answer it and i will mark your answer as solution.